# What am I? The riddle of it

Tags: riddle

They pick me Up
And Wonder
They call me Light

I have Brothers and Sisters
Close, so Close
Together we Serve
That from which we were Born

Ah, I am Free
Yet Fastened
And when I am Unfastened
I can no longer Fulfill
My Purpose

I am used for Travelling
But I am no Burden
I am through which It is done

What am I?

**Hint:**

> tweet tweet's answer (and name, haha) are the closest thus far.

Comment: i would say seat belt but the light bit doesnt fit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you're not a

> wing

then you're a

> feather.

Explanation is basically the same as my other answer (EDIT: which I'm locked out of, I've messed my account up). But it does fit better!

Nice riddle.

EDIT: fits better because

> Everything about flight applies equally well to a wing as to a feather.  But we say "light as a feather". Also, a feather has more "brothers and sisters" than a wing. And "detaching" is less gruesome!

**EDIT** (by question poster, adding this detail for clarity of other users):

They pick me Up
And Wonder
They call me Light

> We pick feathers up, and wonder about them (children love picking them up). "As light as a feather"

I have Brothers and Sisters
Close, so Close
Together we Serve
That from which we were Born

> There are lots of feathers, closely fitting together, on a bird's wing. They serve the bird from which they were born (biologically).

Ah, I am Free
Yet Fastened
And when I am Unfastened
I can no longer Fulfill
My Purpose

> Feathers are free as the bird, but they are fastened to the bird. When they fall off, they can no longer serve the bird.

I am used for Travelling
But I am no Burden
I am through which It is done

> Birds use the feathers for traveling, it is through which the bird travels. And they nearly weigh nothing.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you care to detail your explanation here, I'm sure the other users will want to see why this is the answer :p

Comment: Edited your answer so that the others can see why it was accepted. Well done :) you are also the first one who didn't think of it materialistically, but biologically.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> a wing.

Self-explanatory :-)

EDIT: Very well, explaining anyway!

They pick you up and Wonder, they call you light

> a bird picks up its wings, they are light, and flight is something to wonder at...

You have close brothers and sisters, you serve that from which you were born

> wings usually come in pairs (sometimes more than one pair, eg. insects) and birds are born with them

You are free

> as a bird

Yet fastened and when you are unfastened

> poor bird

You can no longer fulfill your purpose

> poor, poor bird

You are used for travelling but

> don't make me spell that out

You are no burden

> whereas these spoilers are getting tiresome

You are through which it is done

> and I'm done, whew.

Comment: I would suggest explaining it to make the answer complete, but I like the answer.

Comment: No, it's really not self-explanatory. Generally answers without explanation are deleted.

Comment: Very well, I edited in an explanation. The server tells me it needs to be peer reviewed though.

Comment: This is, thus far, the closest answer. Close, so close!!

Answer (score 2):

> Seatbelt

They pick me up, call me light

> You pick it up to buckle it. It is light as in weight.

Brothers and sisters...

> The brothers and sisters are other seatbelts. They all serve the same purpose.

I am free...

> A seatbelt is free to move around, it serves its purpose when fastened, and doesn't when not.

Used for traveling...

> You wear seatbelts while traveling in cars/planes. No burden means you don't really feel it on you when wearing it.

Comment: It does not explain "And Wonder", nor does it explain "I am through which It is done". Good guess though :p

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be:

> A Suitcase

They pick me Up, And Wonder, They call me Light

> *An empty suitcase*. People expect suitcases to weigh a lot, but when they are empty they obviously dont.

I have Brothers and Sisters, Close, so Close,

> There are a lot of suitcases around and when you're traveling there are usually multiple suitcases around. (traveling companions, airplane, bus etc)

Together we Serve, That from which we were Born

> Suitcases were created for the sole purpose of transporting goods.

Ah, I am Free

> Suitcases travel all over the world, which can be considered 'free'

Yet Fastened

> An unlocked / Locked suitcase

And when I am Unfastened, I can no longer Fulfill my Purpose

> An unlocked (open) suitcase can no longer hold any items and can no longer fulfill its purpose for which it was born.

I am used for Travelling

> This one is pretty obvious

But I am no Burden

> People find it convenient to have suitcases around since it allows them to bring more 'goods'.

I am through which It is done

> Perhaps after a long travel when the suitcase is worn?

Comment: This is a good try, but not correct. I'm thinking of adding a hint

Answer (score 2):

You are

> a postage stamp.

---

They pick me Up
And Wonder

> There are many wonderful stamp designs.

They call me Light

> A stamp barely weighs anything.

I have Brothers and Sisters
Close, so Close
Together we Serve
That from which we were Born

> Stamps can have different denominations. You can affix multiple stamps to an envelope and add up their values to pay for the postage.

Ah, I am Free
Yet Fastened
And when I am Unfastened
I can no longer Fulfill
My Purpose

> A stamp is not affixed to anything when purchased. It has to be adhered to an envelope or a mail package to fulfill its purpose.

I am used for Travelling
But I am no Burden
I am through which It is done

> Stamps are used to pay for the cost to mail something to somewhere. Without them nothing can be shipped.

Comment: Good guess! But tweet tweet's answer is the closest one by far, try thinking in his direction!

Answer (score 1):

What am I?

> Headlight

They pick me Up
And Wonder
They call me Light

> Light source, can't connect they pick me up part but may be; there are some headlights which can open/close

I have Brothers and Sisters
Close, so Close
Together we Serve
That from which we were Born

> Fog lamp, brake light, etc.

Ah, I am Free
Yet Fastened
And when I am Unfastened
I can no longer Fulfill
My Purpose

> it is outside of the car so it is free, but it is attached to it so can't work if you remove its connections

I am used for Travelling
But I am no Burden
I am through which It is done

> it is in front of the vehicle, and it can't be a burden because of the low weight

Comment: Unfortunately not, though one of your reasonings is heading in the right direction...I'm not going to say which one though, as it is the key to the whole riddle

Comment: @nine9 another alternative in my mind is a lantern. if it is true i will add it to my answer, otherwise I give up. good riddle indeed :)

Comment: It's not true...but don't give up! The riddle is solvable with one of the lines alone, or well, nearly solvable :p

Comment: mining lamp? :D really not much coming to my mind.

Comment: I'll swap you the answer of my riddle for the answer to your riddle :p

Comment: haha :D well, come to my topic and make a guess ^^ for sure!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a

> photon

your brothers and sisters are

> electrons and protons

they call you light since

> you are actually light

Comment: No, sorry, not the right answer :)